# Counting number of occurrence based on row condition

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have this table, in the left there is the sample input table and on the right desired output

[image: sample input output]

How to calculate the number of status per empid basis using SQL on MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT `emp-id`,
       SUM(status = 'Open') `Open`,
       SUM(status = 'Pending') `Pending`,
       SUM(status = 'Resolved') `Resolved`
FROM source_table
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: meaning of 1 here ?

Comment: @www.friend0.in Positional notation. This means "the column #1 in the output list". I.e. `emp-id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT empid,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Open' THEN 1 END) `open`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) `pending`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'Resolved' THEN 1 END) `resolved`
FROM sampletable
GROUP BY empid;
```

Goodle for "pivot mySQL" for other solutions.